# How to get woocommerce order information inside of wp_head

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is driving me nuts. One of our clients is using a company to track pixels on the site. I'm currently using a snippet I put together to add different tracking scripts to wp_head depending on what page they are on.

One of those if statements outputs a pixel if the page is the Woocommerce Order Received Page (After the customer places an order)

```
if (is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')) { // Order Received Page which contains order ID and Total Price of Order
        $pixel_code = '<!-- Conversion Pixel for [misc]- DO NOT MODIFY --><img src="https://data.adxcel-ec2.com/pixel/?ad_log=referer&action=misc&value=[value]&order_id=[order_id]&pixid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" width="1" height="1" border="0"><!-- End of Conversion Pixel -->';
    }
```

Here is my problem.

I can access the order id and order total amount on the page directly using the following code, and it will echo on page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'pixels_checkout_thankyou', 10, 1 );
function pixels_checkout_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    //getting order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order_id  = $order->get_id(); // Get the order ID
    $order_total = $order->get_total();

    if(is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' )) {
        echo 'Order ID is: ' . $order_id . '<br>';
        echo 'order total is: ' . $order_total;
    };

}
```

[image]

I need to be able to access that same information (Order ID and Order Total) inside of wp_head. I need to replace values in the script tag with the id and total.

So this >

[https://data.adxcel-ec2.com/pixel/?ad_log=referer&action=misc&value=[value]&order_id=[order_id]&pixid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx](https://data.adxcel-ec2.com/pixel/?ad_log=referer&action=misc&value=%5Bvalue%5D&order_id=%5Border_id%5D&pixid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

Would become >

https://data.adxcel-ec2.com/pixel/?ad_log=referer&action=misc&value=**ORDERTOTAL**&order_id=**ORDERID**&pixid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

As you can imagine, the woocommerce order object doesn't work if you try to add it to wp_head with add_action('wp_head', 'function_name');

How would I be able to access the order information to be able to add it to the wp_head portion of the website?

What I tried and doesn't work because the order object is not accessible this way >

```
function testpixel() {
if (is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')) { // Order Received Page
       
    //getting order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order_id  = $order->get_id(); // Get the order ID
    $order_total = $order->get_total();


    $pixel_code = '<!-- Conversion Pixel for [misc]- DO NOT MODIFY --><img src="https://data.adxcel-ec2.com/pixel/?ad_log=referer&action=misc&value=' . $order_total . '&order_id=' . $order_id . '&xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" width="1" height="1" border="0"><!-- End of Conversion Pixel -->';

echo $pixel_code;

}

add_action('wp_head', 'testpixel');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost figured it out :)

Inside the `wp_head` you can use the `get_query_var` to get the `order_id`. After that, it's all easy.

```
function testpixel() {
    // Do things only if on Order Received Page.
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        $order_id    = absint( get_query_var( 'order-received' ) );
        $order       = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $order_total = $order->get_total();

        $pixel_code = '<!-- Conversion Pixel for [misc]- DO NOT MODIFY --><img src="https://data.adxcel-ec2.com/pixel/?ad_log=referer&action=misc&value=' . esc_attr( $order_total ) . '&order_id=' . esc_attr( $order_id ) . '&xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" width="1" height="1" border="0"><!-- End of Conversion Pixel -->';

        echo $pixel_code;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'testpixel' );
```

Comment: Omg you are absolutely amazing!! - Can I ask how get_query_var is able to access the woocommerce order object rather than wc_get_order initially? Does it scrape the page for the information or some other way? This worked 100%, I was SO close!

Comment: If you check the URL of the thank you page, for example, `/checkout/order-received/820/?key=wc_order_Hr0E2CBQNeXDV` you'll find the order id after `order-received` . That parameter is added to query_vars before `wp_head` hook so you can use it there.